# Unable to access the element by id after binding in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am facing problem in accessing the element by ID after binding the data to the HTML. I am trying to access the element by ID using the directive.

The HTML content is binded to a DIV element and I am trying to find by id on the binded content using the **access-html-id** directive, but i am not able to get the matching element though its present.

This is how the HTML content is binded to the DIV

```
<div ng-bind-html="html_data" access-html-id ></div>
```

Code to access the binded html content is as follows

```
myApp.directive('accessHtmlId',function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, iElement, attrs, controller){
                console.log(iElement.find("#hello")); // DOESNT WORKS
        }
        }
});
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong in accessing the element.

Answer (score 0):

Find in jqLite is limited to find only by tag name (not id).

You can review the documentation of jqLite [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Or you can include jQuery in your project, just be sure to include jQuery **before** angular